# dataGridView Cell content not fully right aligned

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have the content of the column right aligned but it is not fully right aligned, there exists a larger than normal gap between the number and the grid line.

Help is greatly appreciated.

[My right aligned text with gap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Y0Is.png)

[Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GSfk.png)

Comment: Probably the column has some padding/margin on the right side?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.